# What's known about basing one-way function on the $P \neq NP$ assumption?

Tags: one-way-function

Is there a conditional impossibility result or the question is completely open?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We cannot hope to prove a general impossibility result since if one-way functions exist (and we believe they do), then in particular it follows that the statement "If $P \ne NP$ then one-way functions exist" is true.

However, we can prove that certain proof techniques are too weak to prove that statement. In particular, the following paper of Akavia, Goldreich, Goldwasser and Moshkovitz proves that this statement cannot be proved by certain black-box reductions (conditioned on plausible assumptions):

http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/p_aggm.html

Comment: What if P != NP and one-way functions do not exist, as might occur if NP = coNP?

Comment: @PhilipWhite we'd be somewhere between Heuristica and Pessiland then, I guess: https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~russell/average.ps

Answer (score 10):

If you mean the cryptographic kind of one-way function (i.e. average-case hard to invert), then Or Meir's answer is great. But for the slightly easier notion of *worst-case* one-way function - that is, an injective function $f$ that is computable in polynomial time, but where there is no deterministic polynomial-time algorithm $g$ such that $f(g(y)) = y$ for all $y$ *in the image of $f$* and $g(y)=0$ otherwise - there is a more precise answer. Namely, worst-case one-way functions exist *if and only if* $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{UP}$.

So for worst-case one-way functions, your question essentially boils down to the relationship between $\mathsf{UP}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$. This relationship is essentially wide open, and there are oracles in both directions. A few relationships for *related* questions are known - namely, Valiant-Vazirani ($\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{RP}^{\mathsf{PromiseUP}}$) and Hemaspaandra-Naik-Ogihara-Selman ($\mathsf{NPMV} \subseteq_c \mathsf{NPSV}$ implies $\mathsf{PH}$ collapses) - but I'm not aware of any direct, unconditional relationship that deals with $\mathsf{NP}$ and $\mathsf{UP}$ precisely.

Comment: That's an ... odd definition for worst-case onewayness. $\:$ (In particular, it implies surjectivity.) $\hspace{.38 in}$ I would've expected it to mirror the cryptographic definition more closely. $\hspace{1.63 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Whoops, I didn't mean to imply surjectivity. Fixed.

Comment: How is $\operatorname{UP}$ involved? $\:$ (Consider the function given by sending pairs [SAT_instance,satisfying_assignment] to their encoded SAT_instance, and everything else to something that's not a SAT instance.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer I think Josh is referring to a result by Grollman and Selman. I do not know the result very well, but I think their definition of one-way function also requires that the function is injective.

Comment: After looking at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397585900854, the definition for a worst case one way function seems to be: 1) $f$ is an injection, 2) $x$ and $f(x)$ are polynomially related in size, 3) $f(x)$ is polytime computable, 4) $f^{-1}(y)$ is not polytime computable for all $y$ in the range.

Comment: @RickyDemer: When $f$ is injective, the range of $f$ - i.e. $\{ x : (\exists y)[f(y)=x]\}$ - is a language in $\mathsf{UP}$.